# frame close and redirect the new url open same window

Tags: php, javascript

How do I close a frame and redirect the new url to open in the same window?

Here the frame closes but does not redirect to google.com.

code:

```
function close_pay3() {
  window.parent.$(".effect" ).hide('clip', 1000 ); 
  return false;
  window.open('https://www.google.com','_self');
}
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="button" onClick="close_pay3()" class="close-btn" value="Login" name="boxclose" />  
</a>
```

Comment: You need to learn JS from basics. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put the all function() inside the popup box.

```
function close_pay3()
{ $(".effect" ).hide('clip', 1000 );
window.parent.document.getElementById('krish').style.display="none";
window.location.href = "https://google.com";
return false;
}<input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.parent.close_pay3()" class="close-btn" value="Login" name="boxclose" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You `return` out of the function before your window.open... Place `return false;` as the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
function close_pay3() {
    window.parent.$(".effect").hide('clip', 1000,function(){
      window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self');

     });

}
```

.

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;"><input type="button" onClick="close_pay3(); return false;" class="close-btn" value="Login" name="boxclose" />  
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

return false; should be in the end after

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self');
return false;
```

Comment: Apply this formate - window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self');return false; - Still it's not working